# Are sub-pixel line-height values ignored by Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using Electron to try to make a native app. The interface has an image of a scanned document as a div background image, with the OCRed text as content. I'm able to match almost all the styles of the scanned document (to a degree that satisfies me, anyway), but line-height is problematic.

The correct size of the font seems to be 10.5pt. When the line-height is set 100%, the content text is a little too high and the text drifts beyond the scan. Set at 99%, it's too small... and 99.5% doesn't seem to make any difference in rendering. This isn't a problem with using percentage values either, as I find the same thing occurs whether I use pixel values, em, or whatever. There are values that cause different rendering, and any fractional values between those are ignored.

If I use the magnification/zoom on this (control-+), fractional values start working, but fail once I've unzoomed.

Are these values being ignored by Chrome, or is it something else which causes this behavior (my montior's dpi, some aspect of font rendering in general I'm dumb and don't understand, etc)?

Is there a work-around for this? I don't need pixel perfect matching on this, but the difference amounts to about 3 lines worth of text, which isn't close enough for my purposes.